# How can I stop unwanted mesh parts to move when parts of my armature moves? Everything is parented correctly. Thanks for any help in advance!

Tags: armature

What you're looking at here is a gargoyle, made up of a torso, 2 wings and a head.
The head was previously alone, then I added a horn, tooth, and an eye and applied a mirror modifier and then finally merged these with the head to become all one object before having it parented by armature.

My screenshots show a couple different scenarios, when I move some of my IK bones, you can see that the bone is also influencing the gargoyles horn and ear on the head and sliding it off the head. This same thing happens on the other side horn when I move the other bones by the head also.
Previously, the head was in several objects (Head, horn, tooth, eye, then I added a mirror modifier to the horn, tooth, eye and applied it and then merged these with the head to be all one object)

I thought this issue was due to the horn (also eyes, eyebrow and teeth) only being "joined" to the gargoyles head rather than "merge", so I tried both methods.

Weight painting has not helped, I have also tried adjusting envelope weights with no luck either. I keep unparenting my armature and reparenting it back to the head, torso and wings

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Select the parts that don't follow correctly, in the Vertex Groups list click on Remove From All Groups, then assign to the correct group?

Answer (score 0):

Wieght paint mode.

in the armature menus, the little stick figure.

select a bone and then ctrl+tab into wieght paint

set what you dont want to move to 0

you have to do a bone one at a time

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your vertices are not correctly assigned, to fix that, select the vertices that don't move correctly and *Remove from All Groups*:

[image]

Then assign them to the correct group:

[image]